# Reserves using Thiele differential equation

Tags: programming, finance, simulations, actuarial-science

I am trying to solve the Thiele differential equations

$$
\frac{d}{dt}V^1(t)=r(t)V^1(t)-b^1(t)-\mu_{12}(t)(V^2(t)-V^1(t))-\mu_{10}(t)(V^1(t)) \\
\frac{d}{dt}V^2(t)=r(t)V^2(t)-\mu_{21}(t)(V^1(t)-V^2(t))-\mu_{20}(t)(V^2(t))
$$

using the R function `ode`. This is the Thiele differential equation for a health insurance with the states 0=dead, 1=sick and 2=healthy. This insurance have an annual sickness benefit payment made to the policyholder when in state 1=sick, this is $b^1(t)$, and no premiums. The reason for having no premiums is because we want to determine a single fair premium to be paid from the time point when a healthy individual turns 50. The health insurance is active from when the policyholders turns 50 up until the individuals 65 birthday. The mortality is described by the cohort mortality given by the Makeham-function:

$$
\mu(t)=a+bexp\{ct\}
$$

where t here should be thought of as age in years. The interest r(t) is assumed to be constant over calendar years, as is $\mu_{12}$ and $\mu_{21}$. There is no mention of any other costs or benefit payments being made when transitioning between states, hence no death benefit.

After I have solved the Thiele differential equations, I illustrate how the reserves evolve as a function of time. From this, I can determine the fair premium assuming that the premium income should equal the expected cost (reserves) in this case.

[image]

The dotted red line represent reserves in state 2=healthy, the other line represent reserves in state 1=sick. My problem is that I was expecting negative reserves since we have no premiums being made. From my understanding, a positive reserve indicates that the insurance company has more funds set aside than it expects to pay out in claims and expenses, and in this type of health insurance it doesn't make sense to me to get positive values.

What am I missing here? Or am i simply reading the plot wrong? I will attach the R code below.

```
# Constants
a <- 3.5e-4
b <- 7e-8
c <- 0.157
r <- 0.03167971
mu12 <- 38.17601
mu21 <- 1.113251

library(deSolve)

exampleODE <- function(t, V, par) {
  tt <- t / par$step + 1
  dV1 <- par$r * V[1] - par$b1[tt] - par$m12 * (V[2] - V[1]) - par$m0[tt] * V[1]
  dV2 <- par$r * V[2] - par$m21 * (V[1] - V[2]) - par$m0[tt] * V[2]
  return(list(c(dV1, dV2)))
}

# define boundary values for the last time point
boundaryValuesEndOfContract <- c(V1 = 0, V2 = 0)   

timeStepYears <- 1
timePointsBackwardYears <- seq(from = 15, to = 0, by = -timeStepYears)
timePointsForwardYears <- seq(from = 0, to = 15, by = timeStepYears)


# define parameters
par <- list(m12 = mu12, # constant intensity
            b1 = 12 * 30000 * 0.15 * (1.015^timePointsForwardYears), # time dependent benefit
            m21 = mu21, # constant intensity
            r = r, # constant rate
            m0 = a + b * exp(c * (50 + timePointsForwardYears)), # time dependent mortality rate
            step = abs(timeStepYears)) # step size needed for indexation

# solve the ODE
odeSolYears <- ode(times = timePointsBackwardYears, y = boundaryValuesEndOfContract, 
                   func = exampleODE, parms = par)

# have a look at the solutions
plot(timePointsBackwardYears, odeSolYears[, 2], type = "l", 
     ylim = c(min(odeSolYears[, 2:3]), max(odeSolYears[, 2:3])),
     xlab = "Timeline", ylab = "Reserves")
lines(timePointsBackwardYears, odeSolYears[, 3], lty = 2, col = "red")
```

One interesting side note: If I opt for a premium paid continuously in time as long as an individual is healthy instead, and set the premium to 1000 annually, I get lower values for my reserves. In this case I use the same R code but with the Thiele differential equations

$$
\frac{d}{dt}V^1(t)=r(t)V^1(t)-b^1(t)-\mu_{12}(t)(V^2(t)-V^1(t))-\mu_{10}(t)(V^1(t)) \\
\frac{d}{dt}V^2(t)=r(t)V^2(t)+p-\mu_{21}(t)(V^1(t)-V^2(t))-\mu_{20}(t)(V^2(t))
$$

where p=1000. This seem to indicate that the reserves in our plot actually represents the amount the insurance company must have set aside in reserves, and not that the insurance company has more funds set aside than it expects to pay out. However, I can't assume this since it goes against what I have read about reserves and that's why I am asking for your help.